# How to remove elements of list of array/structs that have 2 common elements

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

Having a list of structs  OR maybe an array List each with 3 elements, like

```
12 8 7
5  1 0
7  3 2
10 6 5
6  2 1
8  4 3
6  1 5
7  2 6
8  3 7
9  4 8
11 7 6
13 9 8
11 6 10
12 7 11
13 8 12
14 9 13
```

I want to get rid of items that have 2 common subitems in list, in the example I would like to remove

```
5  1 0
6  2 1
6  1 5
7  3 2
7  2 6
8  4 3
8  3 7   has 2 same items as row 7,3,2
9  4 8   has 2 same items as row 8,4,3
10 6 5
11 7 6
11 6 10 has 2 same items as row 11,7,6
12 7 11 has 2 same items as row 11,7,10
12 8 7
13 8 12
13 9 8
14 9 13 has 2 same items as row 13,9,8
```

So using structs approach I am thinking in sorting the list by element A, then looping and comparing elements, in a way that If current element has 2 values equal to other element in list I do not add it to a result List, however I got stuck and do not know if there is a better approach

```
struct S
        {
            public int A;
            public int B;
            public int C;            
        }

public void test() 
        {
            List<S> DataItems = new List<S>();
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 1, B = 2, C=3} );
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 12, B = 8, C = 7 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 5, B = 1, C = 0 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 7, B = 3, C = 2 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 10, B = 6, C = 5 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 6, B = 2, C = 1 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 8, B = 4, C = 3 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 6, B = 1, C = 5 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 7, B = 2, C = 6 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 8, B = 3, C = 7 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 9, B = 4, C = 8 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 11, B = 7, C = 6 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 13, B = 9, C = 8 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 11, B = 6, C = 10 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 12, B = 7, C = 11 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 13, B = 8, C = 12 });
            DataItems.Add(new S { A = 14, B = 9, C = 13 });
            var sortedList = DataItems.OrderBy(x => x.A);
            List<S> resultList = new List<S>();
            for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.Count (); i++)
            {
               for (int j = i+1; j < sortedList.Count(); j++)
               {
                 if (sortedList.ElementAt(i).A == sortedList.ElementAt(j).A || sortedList.ElementAt(i).A == sortedList.ElementAt(j).B || sortedList.ElementAt(i).A == sortedList.ElementAt(j).C)                        
                {
                  //ONE HIT, WAIT OTHER
                }
               }
            }
        }
```

Is there a more efficient way to get the list without having item with 2 same items so I would get, instead of hardcoding the solution?

```
5  1 0
6  2 1
6  1 5
7  3 2
7  2 6
8  4 3
10 6 5
11 7 6
12 8 7
13 8 12
13 9 8
```

Comment: Tried using "Parallel.For" see if the performance increase..?

Comment: Ok, I understand it better with the edit, but I still dont see a `11,7,10` for `12 7 11`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to solve it is by introducing intermediate methods in the `struct S`:

```
public struct S {
    public int A;
    public int B;
    public int C;

    public bool IsSimilarTo(S s) {
        int similarity = HasElement(A, s) ? 1 : 0;
        similarity += HasElement(B, s) ? 1 : 0;
        return similarity >= 2 ? true : HasElement(C, s);           
    }

    public bool HasElement(int val, S s) {
        return val == s.A || val == s.B || val == s.C;
    }

    public int HasSimilarInList(List<S> list, int index) {
        if (index == 0)
            return -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)//compare with the previous items
            if (IsSimilarTo(list[i]))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then you can solve it like this without ordering:

```
public void test() {
    List<S> DataItems = new List<S>();
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 12, B = 8, C = 7 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 5, B = 1, C = 0 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 7, B = 3, C = 2 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 10, B = 6, C = 5 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 6, B = 2, C = 1 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 8, B = 4, C = 3 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 6, B = 1, C = 5 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 7, B = 2, C = 6 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 8, B = 3, C = 7 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 9, B = 4, C = 8 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 11, B = 7, C = 6 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 13, B = 9, C = 8 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 11, B = 6, C = 10 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 12, B = 7, C = 11 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 13, B = 8, C = 12 });
    DataItems.Add(new S { A = 14, B = 9, C = 13 });
    int index = 1; //0-th element does not need to be checked
    while (index < DataItems.Count) {
        int isSimilarTo = DataItems[index].HasSimilarInList(DataItems, index);
        if (isSimilarTo == -1) {
            ++index;
            continue;
        }
        DataItems.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice and easy to read code... Also it is hard to recommend one as it is O(n^2) where dictionary solution in other answer is O(n)...

Comment: Thanks for the complement. And yes, when I posted this I noticed that the other answer is faster as it does double sorting and has upper-bound of O(n). It is of better performance.

Comment: @Ian how would I use your code so I can get both S structs that had coincidende, for instance   `row 7,3,2  and  row 8,3,7` ?  because As I understand var `index`  contains the index of repeated item in List, but How would you keep track of the item that caused repetition?

Comment: @Ian the var `index`  contains the index of repeated item in List, and to get the values Inside main while loop, just before line `DataItems.RemoveAt(index);`  I can get values like `DataItems[index].A,B,C` but How would you keep track of the other repeated item?

Comment: @cMinor Aah, I see... What you probably want is to return the value of `i` in the function `HasSimilarInList` in struct `S`. The easiest way to do this would be to change the return type to `int` instead of `bool`. On `false`, `return -1`, but On `true` (that is, when `IsSimilarTo` `return true` in the loop), change to `return i;`

Answer (score 8):

Given an item...

```
{ A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 }
```

You have 3 possible combinations that could be repeated in another item, e.g.

```
AB, AC & BC which is {1, 2}, {1, 3} & {2, 3}
```

So what I would do is iterate through your list, add those combinations to a dictionary with a separator char (lowest number first so if B < A then add BA rather than AB).  So you dictionary keys might be...

```
"1-2", "1-3", "2-3"
```

Now as you add each item, check if the key already exists, if it does then you can ignore that item (don't add it to the results list).

Performance-wise this would be once through the whole list and using the dictionary to check for items with 2 common numbers.

Comment: Sounds like it is the fastest way. Side note: if code is performance critical (or in generally used more than once) consider using custom key class that contains exactly 2 values (or use Tuple or just anonymous `new { L:1, R:3}` instead "1-3").